# How to debug unity3d on Android/iOS device?

Tags: android, ios, debugging, unity-game-engine

Unity 5.2.3f1 , VS2015 community edition, Windows 10

What I  have already done:

1-built and run the app on windows... everything works fine

2-built for android and deployed the apk on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (using usb cable)...works, but can not debug... 
seems usb debugging is still not an option

(developper mode already activated on device, "development build" and "script debugging" are both checked)

3-used adb commands for wifi debugging:

```
adb tcpip 5555 
adb connect [device ip adress without brackets]:5555
```

device connects as by using

```
adb devices
```

I see my device in the list

4-disconnected USB cable

5- when the game is launched on device, I can see the i-9300 instance of unity in the selection box

6-I choose it and then VS becomes irresponsive... and I need to terminate the program using task manager

any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure breakpoint/step style debugging is possible. You need to capture the logcat using adb (`adb logcat`) and grab the stack trace from it.

Comment: At least one has been able to do that! check this:
http://sebastien.lebreton.free.fr/blog/index.php?/archives/53-Debugging-an-Unity-Game-under-Android-using-Visual-Studio-and-UnityVS.html

Comment: You definitely can breakpoint and step through code on iOS and Android from MonoDevelop and Visual Studio. It can be a bit flaky sometimes though :( I think you need to use the Mono backend rather than IL2CPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, things are better now for testing on android using [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/testing-unity-games-android-visual-studio?playlist=17117) new official tutorial.
Bad news is, you may need to change your windows to a server version.

Comment: You shouldn't need a server version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could export the project as Google project from the build settings. Then from there you can open it in Eclipse or android studio and finally when you run from those IDE onto the device. you can check the debug console. Unity debug should appear there as well.

Same applies to iOS, it is just made more simple, build for iOS, run in xcode onto device, debug shows in console section of xcode.

Comment: Thanks, but it would be the second worst option for me - right before abandoning the project. if I could find an alternative solution, I won't do that. Exporting to Android studio just to debug seem like an overkill. (new toolset, need to work on java instead of c#, and if I go that way, I can not just let unoptimized code be... which means more development time than what we can afford)

Comment: Mmm not really.Just like when you build with iOS, you run the device with xcode and get the Debug. But that does not mean you need to code anything in Obj-C. Using Android Studio would mean you are just opening the project and running, but all of your code is coming from Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with Unity Remote 4 for Android and iOS? It's an application for debugging in Android. You only need to download the app from Playstore and configure Unity to run the game on Android device.

Comment: Actually I did so after you mentioned it. Using Unity remote 4 partially helps debugging on device "if the problem comes from the interface (HMI, interactive objects)". It really runs the code from unity on computer... so in my case it didn't help much as my problem seems to come from loading resources (In fact, I could see levels as they should be loaded... all would be well if mobile compilation worked the same way). I think you response deserves more than -1 reputation that it has for now. thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

goto BuildSetting,select DevelopmentBuild and ScriptDebugging.

make sure your pc and mobilephone in the same LAN.

AND!

**Any dll in your apk, "\assets\bin\data\*.dll",
please make sure the size of dll less than 40M .**

Comment: Thanks for the point, but it's not my case as I don't have any "dll" s of that size...